# how to pass a variable from an activity to another activity using viewflipper?

Tags: android, android-activity, viewflipper

My app contains 2 screens, one having some textboxes on click of which the value in the textbox should be passed to next screen. I have done it using intent, but I want to use viewflipper for sliding effect. Can anyone tell me how to pass value from a view to another using viewflipper?

Comment: hope it helpful.. http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example

Answer (score 3):

As viewflipper belongs to one activity you can just store the value in private field of the activity and then read it another view on flip event.

Comment: Late to the party...but this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one `Activity` when using a `ViewFlipper`.